# SQL Server String Data Types with Django

Tags: sql-server, django, collation, sqldatatypes, unicode-string

I am using Django with DRF to host a production API with SQL Server as our backend. We do not require Unicode data in any of our char/varchar usage, but when I capture the TSQL being compiled by Django, every string value being sent to SQL is defaulting to nvarchar.

Are there any changes to settings.py for my Django project to force the use of UTF-8 when communicating with the database? I also see that Microsoft let's you set your database's collation level, but none of the UTF-8 options translate to my needs directly.

Comment: What Django backend are you using? Be sure to use the backend from Microsoft with the `unicode_results` option set to true, and let Django manage your models. https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django

Comment: Thanks so much @FlipperPA, great note. I am using mssql-django and will give that option a whirl. Will update this to solved if my issue is alleviated. Thanks again!

Comment: If it works, let me know and I'll make it a full answer. The reason you may want to let Django manage your models is that it will create appropriate columns in SQL Server for storing extended characters that appear in unicode. It may be worth creating new tables from your Django models with migrations, and doing a data migration from your old ones, if they weren't created by Django. Cheers!